# Implementing Mutltiple select in dropdown button flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to implement a mutliple dropdown select button in flutter. Something similar to this[image: mutiple select button]

Here is my code

```
   Container(
        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.black12,
              blurRadius: 6.0,
              offset: Offset(0, 2),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        height: 60.0,
        child: DropdownButtonFormField(
           decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: InputBorder.none,
            prefixIcon: Icon(
              Icons.location_city,
              color: Colors.black,
            )
          ),
          items: states.map((String dropDownStringItem) {
            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              value: dropDownStringItem,
              child: Text(dropDownStringItem),
            );
          }).toList(),
          onChanged: (value) {
            setState(() {
              print(value);
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
```

How would i implement it? I know i will have to use a formbuilder but I would appreciate it if i get help or probably pointed to a package that does this seamlessly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try these packages:

- [flutter_tagging](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_tagging)
- [multiselect_formfield](https://pub.dev/packages/multiselect_formfield)
- [multiple_select](https://pub.dev/packages/multiple_select)
- [flutter_multiselect](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_multiselect)